# Conditional loop for a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, nlp, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe (tibble) containing information about sentences. The dataframe has the following structure:

| word | position | category | related_word | sentence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | det | 2 | 1 |
| man | 2 | noun | 3 | 1 |
| sees | 3 | verb | 0 | 1 |
| a | 4 | det | 5 | 1 |
| horse | 5 | noun | 3 | 1 |
| and | 6 | conj | 7 | 1 |
| a | 7 | det | 8 | 1 |
| dog | 8 | noun | 3 | 1 |

I would like to create a loop that looks at every sentence in the dataframe (the sentence number is in the last column),
then if there is a noun in the dataframe (category =="noun"), finds its related word by using the value of related_word in the same row as the noun. The value of related_word corresponds to the position of the related word. The loop would then add both words (the noun and its related word) in a new column (in the format "word" "word").

For the dataframe I provided below, there are three nouns in the first sentence. So the loop would  first use the first noun (=="man"), and find its related word by using the value of related_word (==3). Since this value == 3, that related word is "sees". Then the loop would write in the same row as the word "man" the complete pair, i.e.  "man sees" in a new column (called "pair").

For the remaining two nouns ("horse" and "dog", the new column would hold the following values: "horse see" and "dog see".

How could I approach this? There are a few problems here but the main one is how to use the value of related_word in order to find the values of a different variables. E.g. how can I get from "man" to "sees"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table on itself.. (join on `sentence`, and on `position` equaling `related_word`). Here is a start - perhaps give us more information about what you want the output to look like?

```
df %>%
  inner_join(filter(df,category=="noun"), by=c("sentence"="sentence", "position"="related_word")) %>% 
  mutate(newcol = paste(word.y,word.x)) %>% 
  select(sentence, newcol)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  sentence newcol    
     <int> <chr>     
1        1 man sees  
2        1 horse sees
3        1 dog sees
```

The output can be something slightly different: wrap the above in a `left_join()` [ notice that in this iteration I retain `position.y` in the final `select` statement, to facilitate the join:

```
df %>% left_join(
  df %>%
    inner_join(filter(df,category=="noun"), by=c("sentence"="sentence", "position"="related_word")) %>% 
    mutate(newcol = paste(word.y,word.x)) %>% 
    select(sentence, position.y, newcol),
  by=c("sentence"="sentence", "position" = "position.y")
)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  word  position category related_word sentence newcol    
  <chr>    <int> <chr>           <int>    <int> <chr>     
1 a            1 det                 2        1 NA        
2 man          2 noun                3        1 man sees  
3 sees         3 verb                0        1 NA        
4 a            4 det                 5        1 NA        
5 horse        5 noun                3        1 horse sees
6 and          6 conj                7        1 NA        
7 a            7 det                 8        1 NA        
8 dog          8 noun                3        1 dog sees
```

Comment: This looks perfect. I also tried using the code and it does what I wanted it to. I still have to analyse the code to learn from it but your explanation will help me do that. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have been trying to understand the code above. Why does it say "position" = "related_word"? The way I understarstand how this inner_join function works is that it takes the original dataframe ("x"), uses a filter function to subset nouns, thus almost creating a new dataframe (y), and then uses the values of "sentence" (identical in both dataframes) and "position" (from the original dataframe), and "related_word" (from the filtered dataframe) to join the two. Would it not be better to write "related_word" = "position"? Your code does work but I would love to fully understand it.

Comment: think of `"sentence" = "sentence", "position"="related_word"` as `x.sentence=y.sentence, x.position=y.relatedword`.. Note that we want the related_word number of the nouns (`y`) to match with the position in the x.. You might further see this if you consider that we could do `filter(df,category!="noun") %>% inner_join(filter(df,category=="noun"), by=c("sentence"="sentence", "position" = "relatedword"))`.  Note here that the non-nouns are `x` and the `nouns` are `y`.  Thus we want the non-nouns position to be matched with the noun's related word.

Comment: I took some time but I finally got it. Thanks for the crystal clear explanation.